# Why `seed()` method isn't part of `randint()` function?

Tags: python, numpy, random-seed

It seems that I don't know enough about `Numpy` random methods and functions. Never seen a method that is linked to the function like in this simple example:

```
seed(4)

randint(0,10,10)
```

...where `seed()` is called by `randint()`

I'd like to know:

1. Why seed isn't part of `randint` function as a keyword argument?
2. What's the idea behind this way of creating `Nupy`'s functions ?

Comment: Random number generators work by seeding it **once** and then generating a stream of random numbers afterward. It doesn't make sense to have the seed be an argument of randint.

Comment: That's the old way to do random kept for backwards compatibility. There's a new way where you build a randomgenerator object and call it's functions that's similar to what you seem to prefer: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html

Comment: @CJR: While the new Generator API should be used for new code, its seeding still doesn't work like the questioner is looking for, because seeding like the questioner is looking for doesn't make sense.

Comment: It's perfectly reasonable to set a seed for two different random generation calls and theres nothing in this question that makes me think they want to keep resetting the seed after every integer. I don't know why you're all reading it that way.

Comment: @user2357112 supports Monica Can you elaborate on why it doesn't make sense?

Comment: @PawełPedryc: I did. I wrote a whole answer about it. Scroll down.

Comment: Sometimes we want to repeat a 'random' test case, and use the `seed` at the start of script.  Otherwise leave it alone.  It's not needed for regular random number use.

Comment: Like if I have a rgen in async imap call I sure want to explicitly seed it or else why bother with a seed at all, every time I run it it'll come back different

Comment: @CJR: That's seeding the *generator*, not seeding individual `randint` calls. The questioner is asking why there's no argument to seed individual calls.

Comment: Note that the old API already allows separate, individually seeded generators through [`numpy.random.RandomState`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/legacy.html#numpy.random.RandomState).

Comment: No it isn't - if I can't be sure the generator will always get called in the same order it's got to get reseeded with something that will be the same. That's what this is for: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/bit_generators/generated/numpy.random.SeedSequence.html

Comment: @CJR: No, `SeedSequence` is for if you need to seed a bunch of independent RNGs. You're not supposed to pass a new seed to every single RNG call. You're supposed to give each parallel task its own separately seeded RNG.

Comment: Three comments up you're saying setting a seed for different randint calls is wrong and now you're trying to explain to me how to sequence seeds for different randint calls. Make up your mind. This is a reasonable question and I don't understand why you're all acting like it's stupid.

Comment: Are there cases where we may need two seed()s with different values?

Comment: The specific example I used in the comments is a program that's asynchronously doing work - if you just seed it once, the results will depend on the order in which the tasks are done, which can change every time. You'd want to carefully set a random state for each task instead, if you want reproducible results.

Comment: @CJR: One parallel task receives a seeded Generator, created perhaps with something like `rng = numpy.random.default_rng(seedseq)` and then makes multiple calls, like `rng.integers(0, 10, 10)` (the equivalent of the old `randint(0, 10, 10)`), without passing a seed on every call. You seed the *RNG*. You do not seed individual calls to that RNG.

Comment: about two `seed()`s: I mean cases when we generate two sets of random numbers where for each function the `seed()` value is different?

Comment: Is this the case where it doesn't make sense to use the `randint` function, but instead of another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A seed is meant to determine a *sequence* of RNG results. Like this:

```
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: numpy.random.seed(4)

In [3]: numpy.random.randint(0, 10, 10)
Out[3]: array([7, 5, 1, 8, 7, 8, 2, 9, 7, 7])

In [4]: numpy.random.randint(0, 10, 10)
Out[4]: array([7, 9, 8, 4, 2, 6, 4, 3, 0, 7])

In [5]: numpy.random.randint(0, 10, 10)
Out[5]: array([5, 5, 9, 6, 6, 8, 2, 5, 8, 1])

In [6]: numpy.random.randint(0, 10, 10)
Out[6]: array([2, 7, 0, 8, 3, 1, 0, 3, 2, 3])

In [7]: numpy.random.seed(4)

In [8]: numpy.random.randint(0, 10, 10)
Out[8]: array([7, 5, 1, 8, 7, 8, 2, 9, 7, 7])

In [9]: numpy.random.randint(0, 10, 10)
Out[9]: array([7, 9, 8, 4, 2, 6, 4, 3, 0, 7])

In [10]: numpy.random.randint(0, 10, 10)
Out[10]: array([5, 5, 9, 6, 6, 8, 2, 5, 8, 1])

In [11]: numpy.random.randint(0, 10, 10)
Out[11]: array([2, 7, 0, 8, 3, 1, 0, 3, 2, 3])
```

See how after the second `seed` call (on line `In [7]`), the sequence resets?

When you set a seed, the RNG output still has the same statistical properties, but you can run the program again with the same seed and get the same results. This is useful for things like debugging, or reproducible simulations.

---

If `seed` were part of `randint`, that would reset the sequence every time. It would look like this:

```
In [12]: numpy.random.seed(4)

In [13]: numpy.random.randint(0, 10, 10)
Out[13]: array([7, 5, 1, 8, 7, 8, 2, 9, 7, 7])

In [14]: numpy.random.seed(4)

In [15]: numpy.random.randint(0, 10, 10)
Out[15]: array([7, 5, 1, 8, 7, 8, 2, 9, 7, 7])

In [16]: numpy.random.seed(4)

In [17]: numpy.random.randint(0, 10, 10)
Out[17]: array([7, 5, 1, 8, 7, 8, 2, 9, 7, 7])

In [18]: numpy.random.seed(4)

In [19]: numpy.random.randint(0, 10, 10)
Out[19]: array([7, 5, 1, 8, 7, 8, 2, 9, 7, 7])
```

Same results on every single call. Producing the same results on every call is *not* how we want RNG output to behave.

Answer (score 1):

`randint` is not the only random number/sequence generator in numpy, there are other plethora of random functions, and passing seed everytime to different functions within the program doesn't make much sense, instead, you initialize the seed state once, and then it is used for all random functions.

Comment: I can not say whether there's such cases or not, but I have not seen it so far. Generally, a program has only one seed, and the purpose of the seed is basically to make the output from generator predictable, that means the random generator always generates the same values for a given seed.

Comment: sorry, I deleted the question here - because I posted it above. the question was: Are there cases where we may need two seed()s with different values? @ThePyGuy I've checked that when we create a new instance of `seed` below the first one and the first `randint`, then we are able to generate different sets of random numbers.